# How to handle dynamic changing ID's In XPath?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, xpath

How to Handle Dynamic Changing IDs In XPath?
for example :

```
//div[@id='post-body-3647323225296998740']/div[1]/form[1]/input[1]
```

In this xpath **id** `"3647323225296998740"` is changing every time when reloading the page.

Is there any way to handle this type of situation in Selenium?

Comment: How to Handle Dynamic Changing IDs? for example , ID is `"ss2j7z0k3x5r4y6g1rSROMLLUG65N65Z75U72R61G6eG6dP73Y"`

Comment: Actually dynamic IDs appearing on pages are a code smell that you should be querying.  Particularly addressing the question, 'is it leaking information about the internals of the system?'  In general dynamic ID should be avoided.  Further more, if automated testing is non-functional requirement of the project, suitable ID should be provided as per a proper locator strategy.

Answer (score 21):

At this situation, We have lots of options-

**Option 1:** Look for any other attribute which Is not changing every time In that div node like name, class etc. So If this div node has class attribute then we can write xpath as bellow.

```
//div[@class='post-body entry-content']/div[1]/form[1]/input[1]
```

**Option 2:** We can use absolute xpath (full xpath) where you do not need to give any attribute names In xpath.

```
/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/form[1]/input[1]
```

**Option 3:** We can use starts-with function. In this xpath's ID attribute, "post-body-" part remains same every time.

```
 //div[starts-with(@id,'post-body-')]/div[1]/form[1]/input[1]
```

**Option 4:** We can use contains function. Same way you can use contains function as bellow.

```
 div[contains(@id,'post-body-')]/div[1]/form[1]/input[1]
```

Comment: Imho, option 2 is not recommended,  it is too brittle

Comment: Yes, maximum time we avoids to use Absolute x-path,  but sometimes relative xpath is not working while locating the element, in that case we have to use absolute xpath: in which we have to design absolute path from starting node to descent element node.

Comment: Also, don't forget that you can check multiple parts of an id: constant1-12232-constant2: "//*[contains(@id,'constant1') and contains(@id,'constant2)]"

Answer (score 11):

Use `contains()` or `starts-with()` function in XPath:

**Solution:**

With `contains()`:

```
//div[contains(@id,'post-body')]/div[1]/form[1]/input[1]
```

With `starts-with()`:

```
//div[starts-with(@id,'post-body')]/div[1]/form[1]/input[1]
```

Answer (score 8):

### Use other elements and attributes for partial and combination matches

Generally in these cases of database backed and changing ID's in web element selectors your options are to look for one or more of:

- a higher level selector such as the `form` name, e.g. `//form/input[@type='submit']`
- a combo of non-unique selectors that together are unique e.g. `//form[@class='new_user']/input[@type='submit']`
- a data attribute such as `form[@data-form='new-user']//input`
- a partial match using `starts-with` or `contains` against `post-body-` e.g.
  `//div[starts-with(@id,'post-body-')]/div[1]/form[1]/input[1]`

Answer (score 1):

If the id is changing dynamically for a particular xpath then we can use the below xpath functions:

1. contains :`xpath Syntax: //html tag[contains(text()/@attribute, 'Expected Value')]`
2. Following-Siblings:

   `Xpath Syntax : //html tag/following-siblings::html tag
   ex: //img[@src = 'image2.jpg']/following-siblings::input[@type = 'button']`
3. Preceding-Siblings: syntax will be same as 
   `following-Siblings`
4. The descendant function which is used to identify the grand child node by skipping all

`sub, node from the current HTML tag.`

Comment: I don't think "Siblings" will work in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

The `id` attribute of the `<div>` tag is dynamic which will change each time the webpage is accessed. In these cases you need to construct dynamic locator strategies as follows:

- [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath)

  ```
  //div[starts-with(@id, 'post-body-')]/div/form/input
  ```

> **Note**: The second `<div>` is the first/only child of it's parent, the `<form>` is the first/only child of it's parent, the `<input>` is the first/only child of it's parent, so you don't require the indexes.

- [css-selectors](/questions/tagged/css-selectors)

  ```
  div[id^='post-body-'] > div > form > input
  ```

> **PS**: However a more optimized way would have been to construct the locator strategies based on the attributes of the `<input>` tag only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **regex** in this case, Instead of using XPath you can use some wild cards in **CSS Selector** to locate the same. Please [refer this link.](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/30444/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-identify-xpath-of-element-with-autogenerating)

`input[id^='post-body-'][id$='id pattern']`

[Refer this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for knowing how to use CSS selectors using wildcards.