# How to use a regular expression to identify xpath of element with autogenerating id

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2, xpath

I need to access this element:

```
<input id ="combo-1105-inputWrap">
```

The 4 digits in the xpath are autogenerated per browser session. I need to find that particular xpath and key in the data.

I have tried to use a regular expression in my xpath but I am not able to make this work.

```
//*[contains(id,'combo-1[0-9]{3}') and ends-with(id,'-inputWrap')]
```

How can I reliably access this element?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/405060/can-i-use-a-regex-in-an-xpath-expression gives more detail on using regular expressions in Xpath.

Comment: Try using "//input[contains(@id,'combo-')]".It might work.

Comment: Problem with the "//input[contains(@id,'combo-')]" is that it matchs with all the UI elements present on the page contains the id combo-. But I need to identify only the particular Input box with the combination of "combo-1105-inputWrap"

Comment: Can you add some more html so we can make it unique using parent elements

Comment: provide some more HTML. then you can use xpath axes or  selenium 4 relative operators.

Answer (score 4):

You can use some wild cards in cssSelecter to locate the same. Try below css Selector :

```
input[id^='combo-'][id$='-inputWrap']
```

For further clarification see this :-

```
input[id^='id_prefix_']

input[id$='_id_suffix']

input[id*='id_pattern']
```

You can find more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

Comment: I found this one more helpful in understanding the Regular Expressions