# Xpath is not working using contains and starts with having random values

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

XPath is not working using `contains()` and `starts-with()` functions for below 
 `ID`

`id="u_0_3"`

I have tried with:

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'u_')] - startswith
//*[contains(@id,'u_')]    -contains
```

> Can anyone tell correct path of `id` after `u` is changing randomly and all other attributes like-classname,css are same ?

Comment: Edit & add your HTML code.

Comment: just want to know when there is value changing then what is the syntax or process to create xpath

Comment: In the XPath you are using the hyphen, while in the id there is an underscore. Have you noticed it?

Comment: @Deepti as above comment. Verify you have written dash (-) instead of underscore (_) in xpath. Please post your HTML tag so we can give more ideas.

Comment: ya i know its just typo issue but still not working.

Answer (score 4):

Same like [posted here.](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18342/how-to-handle-dynamic-changing-ids-in-xpath)

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'u_0') and (@class='---')]
```

try with other attributes which are not changing continuously.

Comment: ya thats the one option left.

Comment: @Deepti-Is it works in your case, if yes accept the answer so that it will helps others too.