# How to write XPath if my ID is changing continuously?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, xpath

```
//*[@id='post-9505']/h3/a/time
//*[@id='post-9466']/h3/a/time
//*[@id='post-9517']/h3/a/time
```

In this id number is changing continuously, so how can i write dynamic XPath?

please help me to write XPath for this !

Comment: Please do some search before asking.

Answer (score 5):

Same like [posted here.](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/18342/how-to-handle-dynamic-changing-ids-in-xpath)

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'post-')]/h3/a/time
```

OR

```
//*[contains(@id,'post-')]/h3/a/time
```

try with other attributes which are not changing continuously.

Comment: This is only my humble opinion but answering obvious duplicates encourages people not to put effort to the questions quality which in turn decreases the overall quality of our community.

Comment: It is better to adhere the rules posted here: https://sqa.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer.